# Edit RecyclerView item programatically in Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, cardview

So I have this app in which I have to make a `RecyclerView` which contains a list of items that can be deleted/edited e.t.c.

I followed a tutorial on youtube and I made a custom `CardView` item on another layout and a custom adapter for that item.

Thing is, depending on the state of the item, I have to change something(ex. background color or text color).

When I do that in the `RecyclerView` activity I get `NullPointerException` even if I have the id's.

How can I edit those `TextViews` inside the programmatically generated list of items in the moment I make the Retrofit call?

```
boolean isEnded;
                if(!endedAt.equals("null"))
                {
                    endedAt = endedAt.substring(endedAt.indexOf("T") + 1, endedAt.lastIndexOf(":"));
                    isEnded=true;
                }
                else
                {
                    endedAt="ongoing";
                    isEnded=false;
                }
                item.timeDifference=createdAt+" - "+endedAt;
                if(externalSystem.equals("null"))
                {
                    item.externalSystem="";
                }
                else
                {
                    item.externalSystem = externalSystem;
                }
                Log.i("attr",externalSystem);
                items.add(item);

                itemAdapter=new ItemAdapter(getApplicationContext(), items);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(itemAdapter);
                if(isEnded) {
                error->    externalSystemView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                }
```

The app is rather big, but I think you can get the idea from this piece of code.

Here is the error: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setTextColor(int)' on a null object reference

```
public class ItemAdapter extends     
RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ItemViewHolder>{

private Context context;
private  ArrayList<Item> itemList;

public ItemAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Item> itemList)
{
    this.context=context;
    this.itemList=itemList;
}

@Override
public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout,parent,false);
    ItemViewHolder itemViewHolder=new ItemViewHolder(view);
    return itemViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Item item=itemList.get(position);
    holder.timeDifference.setText(item.timeDifference);
    holder.title.setText(item.title);
    holder.timeCounter.setText(item.timeCounter);
    holder.externalSystem.setText(item.externalSystem);
    holder.type.setText(item.type);
    holder.project.setText(item.project);
    MY IDEA
    "holder.timeDifference.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(item.color));"
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if(itemList!=null)
        return itemList.size();
    else
        return 0;
}


    public static class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    public CardView cardViewItem;
    public TextView title;
    public TextView project;
    public TextView externalSystem;
    public TextView timeDifference;
    public TextView timeCounter;
    public TextView type;

    public ItemViewHolder(View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);
        cardViewItem=(CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view_item);
        title=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        project=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.project);
        externalSystem=
        (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.external_system);
        timeDifference=   
        (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.time_difference);
        timeCounter=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.time_counter);
        type=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.type);
    }
```

**EDIT: I think I found a way, but I don't know if it's the best one**

Comment: Show your code and logcat.

Comment: Add some code. You should be finding views by id's in `holder.itemView`, not `RecyclerView` itself btw.

Comment: I don't think I can check for text changes in the holder tho, I can just declare them there and bind them.

Comment: You perform changes after the widgets have been inflated in OnCreateViewHolder method in your RecyclerView Adapter, and then listen for those changes in onBindViewHolder. You need to add your whole adapter/viewholder code for us to fully understand where you're going wrong

Comment: I updated the answer with the full custom adapter code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution would involve changing your `Item` class a little.

Your problem is that you're not passing over the `boolean` trigger to your `RecyclerView.Adapter` from your `Activity` properly. E.g. `isEndedBoolean`'s value to know what state the item is in. You have the right idea in the use of all three classes.

What I would suggest do is create a constructor in your `Item` class passing the values from your `Activity` to be used in your adapter. I feel it's easier to use `getters` and `setters` rather than assigning the variables straight from code like you have.

So let's begin,

```
 boolean isEnded;
  if(!endedAt.equals("null")) {
     endedAt = endedAt.substring(endedAt.indexOf("T") + 1, endedAt.lastIndexOf(":"));
     isEnded=true;
  } else {
     endedAt="ongoing";
     isEnded=false;
  }
    String timeDifference = createdAt+" - "+endedAt;
  if(externalSystem.equals("null")) {
    externalSystem="";
  } else {
    externalSystem = externalSystem;
  }
    Log.i("attr",externalSystem);
    items.add(new ItemModel(isEnded, timeDifference, externalSystem);

    itemAdapter=new ItemAdapter(this, items);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(itemAdapter);
    itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

You'll notice how I'm adding a new `ItemModel` for each row of variables inside the `RecyclerView` to the array and then passing it that array to the `Adapter`. This is so that it's easier to know what variables are being passed to the Model and thus the corresponding row at the position inside the `Adapter`.

An example of the `ItemModel` class would look something like:

```
public class ItemModel {
    // Getter and Setter model for recycler view items
    private boolean isEnded;
    private String timeDifference;
    private String externalSystem;
    //other variables, title etc etc 

    public ItemModel(boolean isEnded, String timeDifference, String externalSystem) {

        this.isEnded = isEnded;
        this.timeDifference = timeDifference;
        this.externalSystem = externalSystem;
        //only pass to the model if you can access it from code above  otherwise to assign the variables statically like you have.
    }

    public boolean getIsEnded() {return isEnded;}

    public String getTimeDifference() {return timeDifference;}

    public String getExternalSystem() { return externalSystem; }

}
```

The information above is just a guideline for you to create a more efficient model framework to pass the data rather than using static variables.

Now to solve your problem you need to check `if (item.getIsEnded())` and then change the text color corresponding to that `if` condition.

`RecyclerView.Adapter` `onBindViewHolder` would look like:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ItemModel item =itemList.get(position);
    holder.timeDifference.setText(item.getTimeDifference());
    holder.title.setText(item.title);
    holder.timeCounter.setText(item.timeCounter);
    holder.externalSystem.setText(item.getExternalSystem());
    holder.type.setText(item.type);
    holder.project.setText(item.project);
    if (item.getIsEnded() {
    holder.timeDifference.setTextColor(item.color);
    } else {
    holder.timeDifference.setTextColor(item.color);
    }
}
```

The purpose of the `Adapter` is to inflate a layout, bind components to that layout and perform functionality to the items corresponding to the layout at the dedicated position. You need to know which item in your list is in which state, you won't be able to do that from your `Activity` alone. Be mindful of how useful the `Adapter` is in keeping the code from your `Activity` separate from the actual activity of your `RecyclerView`.

Comment: Sorry, I was out for the weekend, but a great way to deal with my problem, thank you very much!

Comment: Happy to help. Good luck.